# Add instance of Window or UserControl inside another Window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have a `Window` which displays a set of `MediaElements` in it. They consume a lot of memory. There is a preview option.

The preview needs to be synchronized with the main `Window`, where the `MediaElements`are loaded and playing.

Presently, I run two instances of the controls which are loaded in the main `Window` and preview `Window` and it slows the entire application down. Sometimes some of the `MediaElements` go blank too.

Is it possible to display an instance of a `Window` or `UserControl`, which is already running or added as a child control, in a separate `Panel`, `Canvas` or `Grid`.

Answer (score 1):

There are known limitations with using multiple `MediaElements`. It isn't recommended as you can [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3b9e40f1-039a-4d4b-b38b-2be2a25544b1/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9fd599fa-6967-480d-9e7e-f72d3dee2e2e).

I would recommend you try using the [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) or the [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library.

The WPF MediaKit provides a direct alternative to `MediaElement`.

It's `MediaUriElement` can be used like so

```
<DirectShowControls:MediaUriElement 
       Source="{Binding ElementName=fileDialog, Path=FilePath}" 
       Stretch="Uniform" 
       VideoRenderer="VideoMixingRenderer9" 
       LoadedBehavior="Play"/>
```

Comment: I tried using MediaKit and it doesn't load the video when there is no audio driver present. Is there any solutions to overcome this

Comment: The source code is available for download. You need to track down what is invoking the MediaFailed event, the HRESULT that is specific to not having an audio device present and prevent it from being fired.

Comment: The `MediaKit` fixes only half of my problems. Do you know a solution for synchronizing the position of videos playing in two separate Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Synchronization Issue with the Main Window and the Preview window by using `VisualBrush` and assigning the `Visual` of it to the Main Window and this effectively helped me to reduce the memory usage.

Referece : Link:[visual-brush-in-wpf](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/visual-brush-in-wpf/)